# Get Top 20 Highest Sales Value in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

We have MS Access 2016 and I need to produce only the 10 top Highest Value of Sales of a listing that is created from a Query. This listing includes 4000 entries but I need to create a listing (To a Table with MS Access, or export to Excel).

Any type of Step by Step process is appreciated since I'm new in MS Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`select top`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/all-distinct-distinctrow-top-predicates-24f2a47d-a803-4c7c-8e81-756fe298ce57) statement in conjunction with an [`order by`](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/order-by-clause-e8ea47f7-5388-460a-bec8-dcc81792d762) clause to sort the dataset by the sales values, for example, something along the lines of:

```
select top 20 t.* from YourTable t order by t.Sales desc
```

Obviously you'll need to change `YourTable` & `Sales` to the names of your table & field respectively.